# Add CSS property to jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I need to set a CSS property in this script to go along with the animation, but I can't seem to do it right.

I need the `div` with ID of "container" to have a CSS property set when the click function is activated. I need an `overflow: hidden` set to `#container`.

Here's my script.

```
$(function() {
    $(".folderContent").hide();

    $(".signin").click(function(event) {
        var folderContent = $(".folderContent");


        var folderContentShown = folderContent.css("display") != "none";

        var clickedFolder = $(this);
        clickedFolder.parent("#signincontainer").after(folderContent);

        $("body").find("#container").not(clickedFolder).each(function() {
            if (!folderContentShown) $(this).not("#signincontainer").animate( {
                opacity: 0.50
            }, "slow");
            else $(this).animate({
                opacity: 1.00
            }, "slow");
        });

        //clickedFolder.animate({opacity: folderContentShown ? 1.00 : 0.70}, "fast");
        folderContent.slideToggle();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$('#container').css('overflow','hidden');
```

Did you try this?

Comment: I tried that, but didnt know where to put that in the script? I only want it to happen when the #signincontainer is shown, but be removed when the #signincontainer is hidden.

Comment: For easier extensibility and manipulation.. I would put that overflow style into a css class and then in jQuery use .addClass() instead of .css(). So then you will call addClass() after you show container and then call .removeClass() when you hide it.

Answer (score 1):

You should just go to the jquery site and read it... it will make more sense and it is really straight forward.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: A minus with no comment? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple to use:

```
$("p").css("color", "red");
```

You can follow this link : [DEMO](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_css_name_value)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add multiple attributes

```
$('select_smth').css({
   'color' : 'red',
   'height' : '10px'
});
```