# Fancybox adding scroll bar to popped up HTML pages

Tags: jquery, fancybox, scrollbar

I am using fancybox to show an HTML page. Whenever the page pops up, there is a scrollbar due to additional space that fancybox is adding. how do I remove this?  I have found similar questions with answers here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532076/add-css-property-to-jquery) that show a solution, but whenever I try them, I can't get them to work. Could someone tell me exactly where I need to put 'overflow:hidden' within my script? Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $(".fancylink").fancybox({
            'hideOnContentClick' : true,
            'width' : 500,
            'type' : 'iframe',
            'padding' : 0,
            'onComplete' : function() {
                $('#fancybox-frame').load(function() { 
                    ('#fancybox-content').height($(this).contents().find('body').height()+30);
                });
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: try adding `"scrolling":"no"` to your options

Comment: well, that gets rid of the scroll bar, but i may need a scrollbar sometimes depending on the height of the page displayed. My problem right now is that fancybox is actually adding space to the bottom fo the page that it's displaying, and it's causing a scroll bar even when the height of the page is really small (40px height, but still shows scroll option). I'd like to get rid of this space that fancybox is adding, rather than completely shutting off the scroll bar every time